# wrap_content leaving extra height when wrapping @string

Tags: android, textview

I've got a TextView with the height set to wrap_content - however, it's leaving a lot of extra space in my app.

The text from the textview is coming in from a @+string and it seems as though the wrap_content is setting it's height to the height of the string variable, not the actual text that's being inserted.

If I replace

```
            android:text="@+string/introGetStarted"
```

with

```
            android:text="Let&apos;s get started!"
```

then it seems to show the proper height and wraps just the text.

Am I missing something?

My full TextView, for reference:

```
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/d15"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/d30"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/d25"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="-10sp"
        android:text="@string/introGetStarted"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="@dimen/d70" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found the answer, it was due to a newline character coming out of the strings.xml file itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your are referencing string resources wrong. Remove the plus

```
android:text="@string/introGetStarted"
```

@+string/ means something like adding new string resource with name "introGetStarted", while @string/introGetStarted means referencing existing resource "introGetStarted"

Comment: Ok, I now see the actual string show up in my graphical layout tab...but it's still taking up just as much space. Replacing the string reference with the string itself shrinks the space.

Comment: Try setting android:padding="0" attribute to your TextView.

Comment: Post your whole layout.xml so we can see what else is wrong. And I was mistaken in previous comment, should be android:padding="0dp", not "0".

Comment: Added my textview above, and the whole file is available here: http://pastebin.com/Pkp6mfeu

Comment: @jlbruno are you sure the TextView is too big? Maybe you are taking it's bottom margin as part of it? Try setting android:background="#ffff0000" and you'll see what space it actually takes.

Comment: Yup, it's definitely the whole textview that turned red. But if I change the android:text to the hardcoded string, the extra space goes away.

Comment: Pretty strange. The way you set the text shouldn't affect it's dimenstions. Is there is an extra red space, or white space? Can you post some screenshots? And why do you need  android:lineSpacingExtra="-10sp"? Try removing it. Should this text be multiline? If no, you should set android:singleLine="true" to your TextView and remove lineSpacingExtra attribute anyway.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23917/discussion-between-jlbruno-and-doctoror-drive)

Comment: Thanks for the help here, I learned that the way the strings were being referenced was incorrect and the debugging helped lead me to the right answer.